Next.js CORS error: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status
Next.js app http://localhost:3000 needs to call an endpoint in http://localhost:3001.
This is the header in the next.config
async headers() {
      return [
        {
          source: '/api/register',
          headers: [
            {
              key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',
              value: 'true',
            },
            {
              key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
              value: 'http://localhost:3000',
            },
            {
              key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
              value: 'OPTIONS, POST',
            },
            {
              key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
              value: 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With',
            },
          ],
        },
      ];
    },

Getting this error on api call
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/api/register' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

How to address the above error? Thanks for your help in advance!
